# How to find an element in JSON array

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json

I have the following JSON data:

```
{"1":{"group_name":"URL","individualize":true,"impressions":1000},"2":{"group_name":"URL 2","individualize":true,"impressions":500},"3":{"group_name":"Funnel","individualize":false,"impressions":2000},"4":{"group_name":"Network","individualize":true,"impressions":1000},"5":{"group_name":"URL","individualize":true,"impressions":800},"6":{"group_name":"Network","individualize":false,"impressions":1000},"7":{"group_name":"Overlap","individualize":true,"impressions":4000},"8":{"group_name":"Viewable","individualize":false,"impressions":5000},"10":{"group_name":"Custom Tactic","individualize":true,"impressions":7000}}
```

How can I find an element in the array by number?

I have the following code so far:

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $http, $filter){
    $scope.names = [
    {name:"Tool"},
    {name:"Initiator"},
    {name:"Result"},
    {name:"Duration"}
    ];
    $http.get("jsondata/data.json")
    .then(function(responses) {
        $scope.table = responses.data;
    });
    $http.get("jsondata/details.json")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.details = response.data;
    });
    $scope.showDetail = function(event)
    {
        //event -> number of element - id in $scope.details array
        //code here
    };
});
```

I tried different functions but nothing happened.

Tested:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

```
  indexOf (jquery, angular).
```

Comment: `$scope.details[id]`?

Comment: return $scope.details[event];?

Comment: $scope.founder = $scope.details[event]; correct! Thank you, dude.